# CONVERT_TZ() equivalent in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I am trying to convert a timestamp value of the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS` to another timezone value `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.SSSSSS`. I was able to do this in MySql using the `CONVERT_TZ(date, from_tz, to_tz)` function,

```
timestamp (varchar): `2018-06-08T23:00:00`
offset (varchar): `+00:00`
```

`convert_tz(timestamp, offset, '+00:00') = 2018-06-08 23:00:00` works fine

How can I do the same thing in Oracle?

I want to pass these 3 values (timestamp, offset, '+00:00') and tried using `from_tz()` in Oracle but was able to just pass two values (timestamp, offset), how do I pass the third value ('+00:00')?

Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTTABLE(id, timestamp, orgId) SELECT NULL, from_tz(to_timestamp('2018-06-08T23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') ,'+00:00'), '1010' FROM IMPORTDATA;
```

This gives: `08-JUN-18 11.00.00.000000000 PM +00:00`

**Desired output**: `2018-06-08 23:00:00.000000`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Both the actual and desired results are the same data, with just a different representation format. In other words, you query works as expected.

Comment: @GMB Is there a way to format the timestamp as `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.SSSSSS`?

Comment: What time zone conversion are you trying to do if offset is the same as the fixed +00:00 value? It also isn't clear if you want to end up with a value that is of `timestamp` data type or another string?

Comment: @AlexPoole It's a coincidence that the offset is same as the fixed value in my example. The offset can be +10:00, +5:30, -8:00 etc. I want the `timestamp` to be of type `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the string and offset separately; `to_timestamp()` gives you a plain timestamp (no time zone) and you can declare it to be from a particular one, which is basically what you are doing already. The result of that is a timestamp with time zone. You then use `at time zone` to convert to a different one. And finally you can convert that back to a string:

I'll use a different offset to make it a bit clearer:

```
select to_timestamp('2018-06-08T23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') as ts,
  from_tz(
    to_timestamp('2018-06-08T23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
    '+05:30'
  ) as tstz_local,
  from_tz(
    to_timestamp('2018-06-08T23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
    '+05:30'
  ) at time zone 'UTC' as tstz_utc,
  to_char(
    from_tz(
      to_timestamp('2018-06-08T23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
      '+05:30'
    ) at time zone 'UTC',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6'
  ) as str_utc
from dual;
```

You don't need those separate results of course, I'm just showing the working.

As you want to end up with UTC you can use a built-in function to slightly simplify it:

```
select to_char(
  sys_extract_utc(
    from_tz(
      to_timestamp('2018-06-08T23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
      '+05:30'
    )
  ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6') as str_utc
  as tstz_utc,
from dual;


STR_UTC
--------------------------
2018-06-08 17:30:00.000000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=754c19af1d7c3abc3aaf20d92a4e81e7)

Alternatively you could concatenate the two strings together and convert them straight into a timestamp with time zone:

```
select to_char(
  sys_extract_utc(
    to_timestamp_tz('2018-06-08T23:00:00' || '+05:30',
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM')
  ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6') as str_utc
from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ca7f87fbe3c885450aa86fe8109265bf)

A date or timestamp (with or without a time zone) doesn't have any real recognisable format; there are several internal representations Oracle uses depending on the context. If you don't explicitly convert to a string with `to_char()` then your client will decide what format to use, via its own settings or more usually via the session NLS parameters, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`, etc.

You should only do that for display though. When storing data in a table, use the correct native data type for the column - in this case, a timestamp. Don't store it as a string. Assuming your target table column is actually a timestamp, and the source staging table has string, you would then do something like:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTTABLE(id, timestamp, orgId)
SELECT
  NULL,
  sys_extract_utc(
    from_tz(
      to_timestamp(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
      offset
    )
  ),
  '1010'
FROM IMPORTDATA;
```

Having columns with the same name as data types is confusing, as is having the same name in the source and target table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and help. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume its probably because of session time format you have. You can check in this way as well.

```
alter session set nls_Date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
SELECT NULL valun, cast(from_tz(to_timestamp('2018-06-08T23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') ,'+00:00') as date) timen, '1010' idn FROM dual;
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works but I have a concern. I specified 3 values `(timestamp, offset, '+00:00')` in `convert_tz(date, from_tz, to_tz)` function. However, in the above query, you've specified just the timestamp and offset. If I need to specify the third value, how to do that?

Comment: Also, how can I specify milliseconds in the `nls_Date_format`? Or do I need to cast to timestamp instead of date?